# Best practice to store and analyze non-equidistant time series data (noSQL/RDBMS)

Tags: database, time-series, analytics, sensors, nosql

We retrieve large amounts of data from various sensor event-based, which means only if the value changes a new data row is recorded in the database.

For many analytics applications this structure is not suitable, (e.g. average, training a forecast model, etc.) so the data must be transformed into an equidistant time series format. I know event-based sensor data is very common, so I am curious which approaches exist to handle this format:

.) Already transform the time series to to an equidistant format in the database, if yes how? 
.) Store the data in the original structure and transform it online (are there analytics tools that can perform this task?)

Comment: Definitely store data as recorded. Use a time-series database which can regularize time series at read time. This gives you some control over the derived series, such as interpolation method, if any.

Comment: Can you recommend any time series database? I found OpenTSDB it can aggregate time intervals, but i didn't find anything about regularization

Comment: Axibase TSD. Here's an example on how you can regularize time series with LAST aggregator: https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/d0e85b27. Disclosure: I work for Axibase

Comment: Okay looks interesting, I have seen there are more than 20 TS databases, do you know if any supports in-database-analytics, so that the data doesn't have to be extracted to R or python to be analyzed?

Comment: Depends on how you defined 'analytics'. Is it custom aggregations or full blown user-defined functions? For custom code to run close to data you have to have a framework in place. In our case, it's the SQL layer that translates SQL syntax into a set of chained filters and calculations. I haven't tried other implementations, so I can't be a good source.